# How to Retrieve a field value from a Glue DynamicFrame by name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

In a Spark DataFrame you can address a column's value in the schema by using its name like `df['personId']` - but that way does not work with Glue's DynamicFrame.  Is there a similar way, without converting the DynamicFrame to a DataFrame, to directly access a columns values by name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `select_fields`, see
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-SelectFields.html.

In your case it would be `df.select_fields("personId")`. Depending on what you want to do, you can save it as a new dynamic frame or just look at the data.

```
new_frame = df.select_fields("personId")
new_frame.show()
```